# sorting list of objects with null properties using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object model MyObject that contains a nullable byte as one of its properties.
How do I sort a list of MyObjects on this key so that the list is ordered by ascending based on the values of this properties, with the objects that have the null appearing last.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: By default, the comparer for nullables places `null` first (is less than everything), thus you'd need a custom `IComparer<T>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - IComparer - If datetime is null then should be sorted to the bottom not the top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734055/c-sharp-icomparer-if-datetime-is-null-then-should-be-sorted-to-the-bottom-no)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linqs [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) comes with an overload which accepts an [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx). This way you can sort the objects all the way you want.

Quick example:

```
public class NullByteComparer : IComparer<byte?>
{
    public int Compare(byte? a, byte? b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return 0;
        if (a == null)
            return 1;
        if (b == null)
            return -1;
        return return a < b ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Use it

```
yourObjects.OrderBy(x => x.NullByteProperty, new NullByteComparer());
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom implementation of the `IComparer<byte?>` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use `??` operator to force `null` values to the back, like this:

```
var res = myList.OrderBy(v => (uint?)v.NullableByteProp ?? uint.MaxValue);
```

You need to cast to `uint?`, because otherwise your nulls will sort together with your 0xFFs.

Comment: This would create a sequence where values of 255 and null values would be interspersed at the end.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, I noticed that too, and quickly added a fix :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx)() function to provide a value when null equal to [Byte.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.maxvalue.aspx)

```
var orderedValues = values.OrderBy(v => v.GetValueOrDefault(Byte.MaxValue));
```

Comment: This would also create a sequence where values of 255 and null values would be interspersed at the end.

Comment: This is pretty much identical to @dasblinkenlight's solution. I recall that his answer (using coalescing operator instead of GetValueOrDefault) is a little more LINQ-to-Entities friendly though in that it gets more readily translated to SQL.