# How can I sort on nullable DateTime fields?

Tags: c#

I have the following line of C# code:

```
dueEvents.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.EventDateGmt.CompareTo(e2.EventDateGmt));
```

`dueEvents` is a List. The `EventDateGmt` fields are each a DateTime. This compiles.

I change it to this:

```
dueEvents.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.EventDateLocal.CompareTo(e2.EventDateLocal));
```

EventDateLocal is a `DateTime?`. This causes the following compiler error:

> CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required comparison type...

How can I sort on `EventDateLocal`?

Comment: What is `dueEvents`? I presume it's a list/collection of some sort. Please also include the class that this list contains.

Comment: Or [C# - IComparer - If datetime is null then should be sorted to the bottom not the top](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4734055/215552)

Comment: Simply change `DateTime.MaxValue` to `DateTime.MinValue` in that linked answer

Comment: If dueEvents is of type IEnumerable (f.i. List<dueEvent>) you can use LINQ to sort. `dusEvents.OrderBy(e => e.EventDateGmt).ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DateTime?` values can be `null` we can't compare them directly. We
should decide if `null` value is less (*nulls first*) or greater (*nulls last*)
than any other value. For instance:

```
// Nulls First
dueEvents.Sort((left, right) => {
  // We have to deal with nulls... 
  if (!left.HasValue) 
    return !right.HasValue ? 0 : -1;
  else if (!right.HasValue)
    return 1;

  // Both left and right are not null, that's why we can do business as usual
  // and compare Values which are not null
  return left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value);  
});
```

Or

```
// Nulls Last
dueEvents.Sort((left, right) => {
  if (!left.HasValue) 
    return !right.HasValue ? 0 : 1;
  else if (!right.HasValue)
    return -1;

  return left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value);  
});
```

Comment: Or just: `dueEvents.Sort((e1, e2) => Nullable.Compare(e2.EventDateLocal, e2.EventDateLocal));`